# blackberry jre4.5, highlight URL

Tags: blackberry

I have an object that extends Field, I use the paint method to draw text using graphics.drawText. I want to have url, and when the user scrolls over it, it gets highlighted. and when clicked it invokes the browser to the link.

like the normal behaviour in the blackberry.

Please direct me.

Thanks,
Aly

Answer (score 1):

You can use LabelField as a button like this:

```
LabelField labelField = new LabelField("label to show",FOCUSABLE){
    protected boolean invokeAction(int action) {
        if ( action == ACTION_INVOKE){
            // browsing...
        }
        return super.invokeAction( action );
    }
};
```